# How to hot swap rebuilt database in an ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a scenario where a an ASP.NET C# based web app is pulling data from a large SQL database that gets rebuilt by a separate app with fresh data every hour or so, the problem is that the rebuild process occasionally causes locks the interfere with the web app. I was thinking about using a second database in order to have one DB rebuild, while the other was being used by the web app, and then have the two switch. What is the best way to manage something like this, or is there a better approach in general?

Comment: Is the only purpose because your getting locks? What's the current usage of the database? Would dirty reads suffice?

Comment: dirty reads would probably be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only Pull data from the DB (not updating and/or making operations) a great idea could be instead of rebuilding the database making an Snapshot the database and work with that one, here are some useful articles that can guide you:

[Database Snapshots (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Understanding Database snapshots](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-database-snapshots-vs-database-backups-in-sql-server/)

[SQL Server Database Snapshots (sqlservercentral)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-server-database-snapshots)

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I'll check it out!